# AWK set values in variables

Tags: awk, csv

I've a `csv` file with some fields with values and I want to print a combination of this values (in the end it will be a `sql` script).

I'm trying to use AWK with no results:

Part of my `csv` file:

```
ATTR_A,2,,
ATTR_B,2,,
ATTR_C,2.5
```

I want to print all the values of the attributes (there are more then the ones listed) in a single string

My final result should be something like:

> The value of attribute a is 2, the value of attribute b is 2, the value of attribute c is 2.5

So that I can easily  transform it in a SQL script something like:

```
 INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`attribute_a`, `attribute_b`, `attribute_c`) VALUES ('2', '2', '2.5');
```

I've tried with this script:

```c
BEGIN {FS=",";}
{

if($1 ~ "ATTR_A")
    $va=$2;

if($1 ~ "ATTR_B")
    $vb=$2;
}

END { print $va $vb}
```

But I get only the print of the last line. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Variables in `awk` are not prefixed by `$`.  If you write `$va`, then you mean "the `va`:th field".

Comment: Do you need the whole actual text shown in the quote: "The value of attribute a is 2, ..."? As it is, each line needs a print. Try this for the awk body: `{ printf ("%s is %s\n", tolower (substr ($1, length ($1))), $2); }`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[,_]' '{ attrs[$2]=$3; };
END{ printf "INSERT INTO db.table (";
     for(attr in attrs) { printf ("%s\047attribute_%s\047", sep, attr); sep=", "; };
     printf ") VALUES ("; sep="";
     for(attr in attrs) { printf ("%s\047%s\047", sep, attrs[attr]); sep=", "; };
    print ")";
}' infile
INSERT INTO db.table ('attribute_A', 'attribute_B', 'attribute_C') VALUES ('2', '2', '2.5')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "," 'ORS=","{gsub(/.*_/,"",$1);print "The value of attribute "$1" is "$2}' filename| sed "s/,$//g"
```

output

```
The value of attribute A is 2,The value of attribute B is 2,The value of attribute C is 2.5
```